# UISearchBar not display in react-native project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

My Obj-C Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTSearchBarTest : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTSearchBarTest

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UISearchBar *)view
{
  return [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
}

@end
```

My js code:

```
var {requireNativeComponent} = React;
var RCTSearchBarTest = requireNativeComponent('RCTSearchBarTest', null);
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <View>
      <RCTSearchBarTest />
    </View>
  }
})
```

I learned it from React-Native's document: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativecomponentsios.html

I tried [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/), the `UISearchBar` is existed, but not displayed.

After I add code `[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 44)];`, it works, but I lookup from [React-Native's code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Views/RCTTextFieldManager.m) I didn't found anything like this.

Is it a bug? Or something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add some styles to your `RCTSearchBarTest`:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <View>
      <RCTSearchBarTest style={{width:375, height:44}}/>
    </View>
  }
})
```

By the way, it is a better practice to name the manager class `XYZManager` and name the view class `XYZ`.